# Mule vm:inbound-endpoint not triggered

Tags: java, mule

I have a list which I want to process in paraller, so after calling `collection-splitter`, I post each record to an outbound-endpoint, but the receiving inbound-endpoint is not been triggered.
Configuration below;

```
<flow name="ProcessPolledOrders" doc:name="ProcessPolledOrders">
        <set-session-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[message.payload.orderBatch.orderSourceName]" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="batchId" value="#[message.payload.orderBatch.id]" />
        <logger message="************* Item: #[sessionVars.fileName] processing resumed. ***********" level="INFO"/>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="PolledOrderSplitter"/>
        </component>
        <set-session-variable variableName="size" value="#[message.payload.size()"/>
        <collection-splitter/>
        <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="#[sessionVars.size]" />
        <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[sessionVars.fileName]" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <payload-type-filter expectedType="model.Order"/>
                <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="step2" doc:name="VM"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <echo-component/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>

<flow name="PollerOrderProcessingFlow" doc:name="PollerOrderProcessingFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="step2" doc:name="VM"/>
        <logger message="***************** Validating order with id #[message.payload.id] ********************"
                level="INFO"/>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="PolledOrderValidationComponent"/>
        </component>
        <collection-aggregator timeout="600000" failOnTimeout="false"
                               doc:name="Validated Orders Aggregator"/>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="BatchOrderUpdateComponent"/>
        </component>
        <default-exception-strategy>
            <flow-ref name="ValidationProcessingExceptionFlow" />
        </default-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any exception? try to debug and see where the message dropping? I tried similar flow and working fine for me.

Comment: No exception, at least nothing is been logged